# Left off(in a sentence usage)

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Let's say you were **watching a video yesterday**, but you felt you had to go to bed coz' you got tired from streaming videos all day. And then you pick back up to where you left off yesterday, and you say:

> Oh! This is the last part **where I left off** yesterday.

Can you really say this without the ''pick up'' included in a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example sentence is not really normal usage.

You could rephrase it in a couple of ways:

> Oh! This is where I left off yesterday.
>   Oh! This is where I was yesterday.
>   Oh! This is the last part I saw yesterday.

But *the last part where I left off* is a little strange.

You certainly don't *need* to include "pick up" in the sentence. But you could if you wanted to:

> Oh! Let me pick up where I left off yesterday.
>   Oh! I think I'll pick up where I left off yesterday.